# Display none property stops youtube iframe playback in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, youtube

On the page I have a div with few youtube iframes. On Chrome and Safari I don't have problems with the playback when I slideUp the container. If a video is playing the sound keeps going. When I open the site in Firefox and play a video then slideUp the container the iframe looses state and the sound stops. I know that if I refactor the code and use

```
visibility: hidden;
```

on the container and

```
visibility: visible;
margin-top: -2000px;
```

on the video it will work but I really want to find a faster solution so can somebody help?

Comment: Use `visibility:hidden;` I had the same issue with the youtubeAPI when docking the player.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just replaced the `slideUp` animation with `animate({ height: 0 })` and its working. Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
opacity:0
```

or

z-index:-999

Comment: I call slideUp on the container so jQuery automatically puts display: none on it and the video stops.